# How is combat damage calculated in Sorcery?

Tags: ios, sorcery

In [Sorcery!](https://itunes.apple.com/nz/app/sorcery!/id627879091?mt=8), how is it determined what damage to stamina you do to your enemy or your enemy does to you? The game says that when you defend you are inflicted minimal damage. Does this mean that the stronger your attack the more damaged in the end you are (given that the opponent attack was even stronger)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One source gives these numbers : "So if you charge at your opponent with 10 attack power, and he defends with 0 attack power, he takes 1 point of Stamina damage. However if you attack with 10 attack power and your opponent attacks with 5, he would take 2 points of damage. If he had attack with 9 instead, he would take 3 points of damage." http://www.rpg.net/reviews/archive/15/15864.phtml

They seem to be in the right direction. What the exact algorithm is, I'm not sure.
If you note down some more results, we could make an educated guess at it.

Comment: While it does not really answer the question, I'm going to accept it for trying because *some* answer is better than none, and it's quite possible that this answer is the best I can hope for.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can figure if you defend no matter the attack you take one stamina damage. If you both attack over 5 power the lower attacker receives four damage. If you attack abouve five and the opponent attacks below five you take 2 damage. If you both attack below five the loser receives two damage. Stamina damage is fairly simple but I can not for the life of me work out the formula for you available attack power. There seems to be no correlation between how much power you use and how much you can use next time or when sometimes you earn power and sometimes you lose. So that's the best I've got.